# Custom GridView Adapter not displaying

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-adapter

I'm creating a list of "channels" on an app that users can select. I want them in a grid view, (kind of like clickable tiles). There are supposed to be *two* separate Grids on this Fragment - default channels (`channelListSupplied`) and ones that the user will have to request subscriptions to (`channelListEarned`).

I used a custom adapter that I got from another answer here on SO, but I can't get it to work because it's in a Fragment instead of in the Activity, and I'm sure there's some reference I'm not passing correctly.

Below is a list of the relevant pieces of Java and XML...

`FragmentChannels.java`: (fragment to `MainActivity.java`)

```
public class FragmentChannels extends Fragment implements FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener {

    ViewGroup container;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        final JSONObject channelList = data.getJSONObject("channels");
        final JSONArray channelListSupplied = channelList.getJSONArray("supplied");
        final JSONArray channelListEarned = channelList.getJSONArray("earned");


        GridView channelViewSupplied = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.channel_grid_supplied);
        GridView channelViewEarned = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.channel_grid_earned);

        if (Session.getSessionVar("canHasSpecial").equals("1")) {
            FragmentChannels.this.createGridView(channelViewEarned, channelListEarned, FragmentChannels.this.container);
        }

        FragmentChannels.this.createGridView(channelViewSupplied, channelListSupplied, FragmentChannels.this.container);
        ...

        return view;
    }

    public void createGridView(final GridView gridView, JSONArray list, final ViewGroup container) throws JSONException {

        final String[] gridList = new String[list.length()];
        final Activity activity = getActivity();

        for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject channelData = (JSONObject) list.get(i);
            gridList[i] = channelData.getString("source_name");
        }

        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                gridView.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(activity, gridList, container));
            }
        });
    }


    public boolean createChannelMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater  = this.getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_channels, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Activity activity = getActivity();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackStackChanged() {

    }

}
```

`GridViewAdapter.java`:

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private final String[] textViewValues;
    private ViewGroup container;

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, String[] textViewValues, ViewGroup container) {

        this.context = context;
        this.textViewValues = textViewValues;
        this.container = container;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.textViewValues.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return textViewValues[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.d("CDFF", position+": "+this.textViewValues[position]);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_layout, this.container);

            TextView titleView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_title);
            titleView.setText(textViewValues[position]);
        }

        else {
            gridView = convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }
}
```

`fragment_channels.xml`:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="FragmentChannels"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_channel_container"
    tools:context="xx.xxx.xxxx.FragmentChannels"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:text="My Channels"
            android:background="@color/peach"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/midnightBlue"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.FontPath"
            />

        <GridView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/channel_grid_earned"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:columnWidth="180dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:clickable="true"/>

        <GridView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/channel_grid_supplied"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:columnWidth="180dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="auto_fit"
            android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
            android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:clickable="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

`grid_item_layout.xml`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_image"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/grid_item_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

As of now, nothing displays on the Fragment except the "My Channels" TextView.

I greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: please show complete code of Adapter

Comment: Hi. I've added the entire adapter class as requested. I've narrowed it down to the getView() being caught in an infinite loop.

Comment: update to the latest recyclerview in your gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed.

I changed the line:

```
gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_layout, this.container);
```

To:

```
gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item_layout, null);
```

in the `GridViewAdapter.java` class.